# Any curve parametrized by two polynomials $x(t)$, $y(t)$ solves some polynomial equation $f(x, y) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Exercise from Artin's *Algebra*, Chapter 3:

> **M.3 (c)** Prove that every pair $x(t)$, $y(t)$ of real polynomials satisfies some real polynomial relation $f(x, y) = 0$.

**My "head-on" attempt:**

Substituting $x(t) = \sum_{i = 0}^m a_i t^i$ and $y(t) = \sum_{i = 0}^n b_i t^i$ in $f(x, y) = \sum_{i = 0}^p(\sum_{j = 0}^i c_{ij} x^j y^{i-j})$, we can conclude that there exist $d_{ijk}$'s such that
$$f(x(t), y(t)) = \sum_{i = 0}^p\sum_{j = 0}^i c_{ij}\left(
\sum_{k = 0}^{ni + (m-n)j} d_{ijk}t^k
\right),$$
which is a degree $p\times\max(m, n)$ polynomial.

What I now intend is to show that the coefficient of each $t^k$ is a linear combination of $c_{ij}$'s.$^1$ Though this seems obvious on the face of it by looking at the above equation, I am not able to show this rigorously. Induction on degrees seems of no help here. I tried reorganizing the sum so that $k$ is  the "outermost index", but to no good.

**Question:** Any help in this method? Or an alternate approach?

---

$^1$Equating them all to zero will give me a linear homogeneous system of $p\times\max(m, n) + 1$ equations in $(p+1)(p+2)/2$ variables (which is the total number of $c_{ij}$'s), and then I can choose a sufficiently large $k$ to ensure that there are more variables than the equations.

Comment: You need to eliminate $t$ between the equations $\,X=x(t), Y=y(t)\,$. One way is using polynomial [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Application_to_polynomial_systems).

Comment: @dxiv I had a look at the Wiki page on resultants you mentioned. But that seems a lot more overly complicated than my proposed proof idea.

Comment: Your idea is reminiscent of the [determinant form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition) of the resultant, and probably just as complicated once you fill-in all the remaining blanks.